# Offline WebApp on iOS using CDN

Tags: ios, web-applications, manifest, offline, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to setup offline support for our webapp. I would love to use a serviceWorker for that but unfortunately Safari does not support those, yet.

So I tried using the deprecated manifest file. But apparently only files from the same origin are allowed in there. We are loading our static files from a CDN (so the origin is not the same).

Is there any way to make a webapp with CDN files work offline on iOS?

One last idea would be to generate a index-offline.html file, include that one as a FALLBACK in the manifest. In there, I would point to the same files but this time not on the CDN but on our own server... But this does not seem like a nice solution to me.

Thanks in advance :-)

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

As long as iOS does not support service workers, you cannot make offline work.  Service worker is the core of a PWA and that can make offline work properly.  We as still not sure if iOS will support offline capabilities.